# Accessing Salesforce Chatter API with a token from an external IdP

Tags: chatter, oauth2, single-sign-on, authentication

We're working on a Java/Angular app and using Auth0 as an OAuth2 provider. Now, there's a need to integrate with Salesforce's Chatter API. As far as I can see, that API doesn't support sending messages in favor of another user? Meaning we can't use a single "system" user for this integration, but we have to authenticate every user of our app to Chatter API independently? And that's where the problem starts. :)

The only thing we have is a token issued by Auth0. The question is: **how to use that token to access Chatter API?**

I've been playing with every SSO/auth option in Salesforce but I'm still completely lost. We'd like to keep using Auth0 as the main IdP and configure Salesforce to use it. Any suggestions how to configure all this in order to keep using Auth0 login and be able to communicate with Chatter API?

Comment: Can you be specific what is your requirement here with Salesforce Chatter? What data are you trying to use from Salesforce chatter?

Comment: You need a Salesforce-issued token.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Users of my app need to be able to participate in communication (read/write chatter feed items that are linked to certain Salesforce objects).

Comment: @identigral Sure, but is there a way to get it while keeping Auth0 as the primary identity provider?

Comment: Are users in salesforce provisioned in AD or Auth0? Where are users provisioned and how do you envision SSO between Salesforce and Auth0?